# Writing macro/formula to match data from 2 different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to run a macro or figure out which formula i can use to match data from one worksheet to another.

Worksheet 1: Has the product ID and empty column for product status
Worksheet 2: Has the product ID and status for the corresponding ID

Basically, I am trying to do "if the product ID is this..then it should equal ".." in the status column for worksheet one

Comment: XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

Entering the following formula in cell B2 of `Worksheet1` will extract the `product status` from `Worksheet2` for the `product ID` present in cell A2 of `Worksheet1`.

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Worksheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

On `Worksheet2`, column A must contain your product ID list and column B must contain your product status list.

Copy the formula down as needed.

cell B4 on Worksheet1 contains `=VLOOKUP(A3,Worksheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

cell B5 on Worksheet1 contains `=VLOOKUP(A4,Worksheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

etc...

or, you can also use the following formula in column B of Worksheet1:

`=VLOOKUP(A:A,Worksheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Excel automatically determines which row number to use...there's no need to enter A2, A3, A4, etc. in each successive formula.

Comment: Although code answers are acceptable can you add some explanation. Your answer will be read by people in the future so you need to add a description so that they can understand your solution.